# Convert coordinates from iPhone screen size to iPad screen size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have a custom UIView that contains an interactive drawing that is drawn in the drawRect function of the view. On the iPad the drawing size is 1024 x 768. For the iPhone I shrink the drawing for the iPhone using CGContextScaleCTM. To keep the proper aspect ratio on my drawings I shrink the view to 480 x 360 and set the y value of the view  to -20 (effectively cropping 20 pixels off the top and bottom of the View, which is fine). Everything looks correct now, but I need to convert the touch coordinates from iPhone to iPad coordinates for the interactive portions of my view to work. If I make the uiview 320 high and use

```
point.y *=768/320
```

for converting the y value the locations are correct (but my drawing is distorted) I've done some tests hard coding point in so I know this should work but I'm having a hard time getting the math to work with the crop. Here is what I have so far:

```
CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
[self endTouch:&point];
NSLog(@"true point: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
point.x *= 1024/480;
point.y *= 768/360;
NSLog(@"corrected point: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}
```

Can anybody help me with doing this conversion? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1024/480` and `768/360` perform integer division.  The result of both operations is `2`, but you really want `2.133333`.  Replace the relevant lines in your code with the following:

```
point.x *= 1024.0/480.0;
point.y *= 768.0/360.0;
```

This will return the value you're looking for and scale your point's `x` and `y` values accordingly.

You might be better served (in terms of readability) by replacing these literals with a `#define` macro.  At the top of your code, put the following:

```
#define SCALING_FACTOR_X (1024.0/480.0)
#define SCALING_FACTOR_Y (768.0/360.0)
```

and then modify your code to use that:

```
point.x *= SCALING_FACTOR_X;
point.y *= SCALING_FACTOR_Y;
```

That way, it will be more clear as to what you're actually doing.

Comment: Thanks!That explains the weirdness I was getting before. Thanks for the tip on the #define macro as well. Is that a C thing or and objective-c thing? I have seen these used in bits of code from around the net but hadn't come across them in any of the objective-c books I started learning from.

Comment: @jonmorgan What is the reverse? I need to convert iPad coordinates to iPhone coordinates. Any tips?